# How to do Error in Variables regression with known standard errors

Tags: regression, standard-error, errors-in-variables, total-least-squares

I need some help with EiV regression and comparison of two methods.

I have used two different methods to estimate the size of the same population and would like to find out how good method 1 is relative to method 2, and if there is a linear relationship between them. I have several estimates for every method, and for every estimate I have a standard error.

Let’s say for method 1, I have the estimates $x_1, x_2,\dots ,x_n$, with standard error $SEx_1, SEx_2,\dots,SEx_n$ for each estimate $x$. For method 2, I have the estimates $y_1, y_2,\dots ,y_n$, with standard errors $SEy_1, SEy_2, …, SEy_n$ for each estimate $y$.

I have read about orthogonal and Deming regression and also tried that in R, but I haven’t found out how to include the $SEs$ of my estimates.
So, my question now is, how can I do an EiV regression in R with the two methods which allows me to include the $SEs$ of the estimates of both methods?

Any hint would be appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: For the question of y ~ x have you had a look at the deming package? Its deming function has an explicit xstd and ystd argument which takes vectors as input.